# Run print PDF with powershell and PHP

Tags: php, powershell, pdf, printing

I tried many things without success
Below is the PHP script that executes my powerShell file

```
/**
     * @Route("/bat", name="app_bat")
     */
    public function bat(): Response
    {
 
        $route = 'C:\wamp64\www\Intranet\bin\print.ps1';
        $process = new Process(['powershell', $route]);
        $process->run();
        // executes after the command finishes
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_print_empl');
    }
```

and here is my powerShell file which launches the print and deletes the PDF file,
when I launch it manually, it works fine, the file prints and then deletes itself.

```
$MYFILE = "C:\wamp64\www\Intranet\public\ean.pdf"
 
Start-Process -FilePath $MYFILE -Verb print -PassThru
 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
Remove-item C:\wamp64\www\Intranet\public\ean.pdf
```

On the other hand, as soon as I launch it from my PHP script (intranet server under WAMP and Windows 11, inflated PC), the file is deleted correctly but does not print ....

In my testing I found that when I run the powershell script below from PHP, it prints and deletes, the problem being that it prints a lot of extra page with lines of code.... ..

`Get-Content -Path C:\wamp64\www\Intranet\bin\ean.pdf | Out-Printer`

I print labels with EAN code, so the code that is printed in addition represents around 600 labels XD

Do you have a solution, I carried out an incalculable number of tests .... please help me

Thank you for taking the time to read my request and for those who will answer it :)

I have tried all the codes on these pages
https://techexpert.tips/fr/powershell-fr/powershell-impression-dun-fichier/
https://techexpert.tips/fr/powershell-fr/powershell-configurer-limprimante-par-defaut/

I put PowerShell in 'unrestricted' for all

And what I would like is that it finally prints :)

Comment: Have you tried using `Start-Process -Wait ...` instead of sleeping?

Comment: Hello, yes, I tried start process, but it doesn't start printing with PHP

Comment: it's this printer https://www.europrocess-label.com/imprimantes-thermiques/713-sato-ws408-tt-203-dpi-imprimante-de-bureau-derouleur-rs-232.html

Comment: a label printer, but on the other printers in the company network, I have the same problem